# how to read through a list of files in c

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I am trying to read through a list of files in C using a for loop however it only reads the first file and then exists the for loop and I'm not sure why. I am new to C so I am probably making a dumb mistake but I have been stuck on this for a while now. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000


char* fileNames[] = {"file1.csv", "file2.csv"};
FILE* fp;                 //pointer to file

int main(){

  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(fileNames[i])/sizeof(char *); i++){
    fp = fopen(fileNames[i],"r");
    char line[MAXCHAR];

    //If file can't be read
    if(fp == NULL){
      printf("Could not open file %s","latitude.csv");
      return 0;
    }

    printf("Reading file %s\n",fileNames[i]);
    while(fgets(line, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL){

    }
    fclose(fp);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray array subscript in your size calculation which causes your loop to terminate after only 1 iteration: `sizeof(fileNames[i])/sizeof(char *)`.

Change that to: `sizeof(fileNames)/sizeof(fileNames[0])`

Comment: ......ommmmmggggggg......hours for this..........are you kidding me *face palm*. THANK YOU!